# Hiding li elements when screen width changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have main horizontal menu based on the `<li>` elements. I am trying to make it responsive - it usually covers the whole screen. What I need to do is hiding the last li element when the screen is not capable of displaying it in the same line (hiding and possibly adding it a new class, jquery) and showing it again when the browser window is changed to the default.

I tried many different solutions and I usually come up with tons of code and having to add each li a separate class. Is there any way to do that more easily?

If you could provide me with some guidelines, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Could you post your basic look of Result along with code. Better if you could create [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) here.

Comment: couldn't you just float the li's left, give the ul a fixed height and set the ul overflow: hidden; ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to hide the last menu element depending on browser width? Doesn't sound very accessible.

Anyway you don't need to use anything in javascript to achieve this. Make the menu items either float:left or display:inline-block so that that last element will break the line, so this element is moved to the next line. 
Then on the , put overflow: hidden and make sure the height of the  is the same height as a menu item. This way, all overflow menu items will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
li:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Put it in a media query. For e.g like this:

```
@media (max-width: 400px)
```

(When you add css here, it will apply only when screen resolution is less than 400px).

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s634fjvk/

**EDIT**: Adding new possible solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/s634fjvk/1/

Comment: this method will fail once the length of the menu items change

Comment: Why should it fail? He wants to hide last item every time.

Comment: whether or not the last menu item will fit depends on the width of the menu items. So if one of the menu items will contain less or more text after a content change, the css limit (400px) should also be updated every time

Comment: I think you are aiming in wrong direction. 400px is for screen width in this example.. and is here only to show how OP can hide last 'li' item in his 'ul'. I could go without that part in example but I choose to go with this one to make job easier for Pawel Ryszka. 

:last-child is important part here.

Comment: OP said to hide it 'when the screen is not capable of displaying it in the same line' and was thinking about a javascript solution to measure whether this is the case, so it's likely that the menu items have dynamic width, which is why a fixed media query limit is probably not what he wants.

Comment: Than it was my mistake. Maybe he can use media q. with "height" as parameter ..if there is a problem only with last item. Or setting max-height for 'ul' and 'overflow: hidden' ?! Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/s634fjvk/1/

Comment: yea that fiddle is what we suggested, i guess this is what he wants, but it's a strange idea nonetheless

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answers. Why do I want to use javascript? To place li elements that are hidden into a previously hidden menu icon, which appears only if any of the items is hidden (it's like the menu icon visible on all responsive sites while viewing them on mobile).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using boostrap?  they have plenty of tools to make responsive lists and navbars

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group

You could try doing something like this,

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
     </div>

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">        
             <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
             <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

I haven't tested this but I think it may be a good place to start.

Comment: You will need to download Boostrap and upload the files for this to work.